# I need to write a filter that will log a login attempt and printout to a jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, web-applications, filter

I need a filter that will record a login attempt and then print to a jsp that there was a login attempt. I'm a but puzzled in how to do this? I'm a newbie so please be patient. Thank you.

Here is my index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>First Web App</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="LoginServlet" method="post">
    <div><h2>My First Webapp</h2></div>
    <p></p>
    <div><h3>User Name:<input type="text" name="username" id="username"></h3></div>
    <p></p>
    <div><h3>Password:<input type="password" name="password" id="password"></h3></div>
    <p></p>
    <input type="submit" value="login" id="loginsubmit"/>
     </form>
</body>
```

Here is my servlet

public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException    {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

        try {
            if (username.equalsIgnoreCase("admin") && password.equalsIgnoreCase("password"))   {
                HttpSession session=request.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("username", username);
                RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp");
                rd.forward(request, response);
                                                                                            }
        else
            {               
                response.sendError(response.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Denied Access");                               
            }
            }

        finally 
            { 
                out.close();
            }


                                                }
```

Here is a very small and pitiful start to my filter, I'm just stalling on this part:

```
public class AuditFilter implements Filter {

public AuditFilter()    {
                                }    

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    String audit = request.getParameter("audit");
    if (audit != 


    }
```

Any guidance would be very helpful.

Comment: wide range question, because you can approach it in very different ways.
At first you have to store last login attempt somewhere eg. at ServletContext or database. And is your project even copiling? Did you override doPost and doGet methods somewhere?   Edit: and i really dont understan why ppl put code in try clause without any catch statement...

Comment: Project does work, I didn't post all of the code so I understand that it may look a tad odd. So I guess what I want to do is tell another .jsp that someone is trying to login to the webapp. So I would system.out.print to a new .jsp.....I'm looking as simple as possible because I'm learning this for the first time. Building up my skills so to say...

Comment: if you just want to view current login attempt, pass its value to the request.setAttribute("log",yourString), then redirect to jsp, and in .jsp do something like <%=request.getAttribute("log")%>